# Blender Metarig to Houdini

Tags: export

Is it possible to use Pitchipoy's metarig in Houdini? 
Tried to export it, and Im able to get it into H, but its messed up.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Im new to Houdini, and was hoping i could use some rigs and stuff from Blender.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the character in Blender and export it with the animation using Alembic.Then you just import it to Houdini and voila. It's very straight forward process.